# .NET Inline expression for RequiredFieldValidator ErrorMessage

Tags: asp.net, .net, expression

I am trying to make the error message for my Required Field Validator dynamic by using a .net inline expression.

I have a drop down menu with three list items- First Name, Last Name, and Phone Number.

The user selects a list item and then inputs text into a textbox. If the textbox is empty, the RFV fires the error message.

I want the error message to contain the list item selected in the drop down. Here is my code.
Drop down:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="drpSearchField" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-outline-secondary">
```

RequiredFieldValidator:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvSearch" runat="server" 
ControlToValidate="txtSearchData" EnableClientScript="true" ErrorMessage=" 
<%$ drpSearchField.Text %> is required." ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Answer (score 0):

since <% %> is evaluated on server side before providing HTML for client, it has no clue about what user selected few minutes or even hours later.

You'll need some javascript to update your error message text when your drpSearchField value is changed on client. Something like

```
drpSearchField.Attributes("onchange")="javascript: " & rfvSearch.UniqueID & ".errormessage = getSelectedText(this)+" is requried.";
```

where getSelectedText is some javascript function to get your DDL currently selected text.